# Sum of a linear invertible function and another Lipschitz function with Lipschitz constant sufficiently small is also invertible

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a linear invertible function $T(x):\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$, and another Lipschitz function $g(x)$ with Lipschitz constant $C$. $f(x)=g(x)+T(x)$. How to prove that, with $C$ sufficiently small, $f(x)$ is also invertible?

Comment: Banach fixed point theorem?

Comment: Would you elaborate a little pls

Comment: Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Applications) , which explains that "One consequence of the Banach fixed-point theorem is that small Lipschitz perturbations of the identity are bi-lipschitz homeomorphisms" and goes on to solve your problem.

Comment: thank you for the direction!